# GSON just to read a JsonObject tree from Json data doesn't work

Tags: gson

I'm using GSON for a project. In particular I use this code to generate JSON strings:

```
Gson gs = new Gson();
        JsonObject cmdobj = new JsonObject();
        cmdobj.addProperty("cmd", cmd);

        cmdobj.add("arg", args);

        String cmdstr = cmdobj.toString();
```

which produces something like:

```
{"cmd":"HANDSHAKE","arg":{"protocol":"syncmanager","serverName":"12345678910"}}
```

then on a client machine this reads the json data:

```
String cmdstr = readCommand(this.is);
        Gson gs = new Gson();
        JsonObject jsobj = gs.fromJson(cmdstr, JsonObject.class);
        JsonElement cmd = jsobj.get("cmd");
        JsonObject args = jsobj.get("arg").getAsJsonObject();
```

the problem is that jsobj that should contain the parsed object doesn't contain anything ( if I do toString() prints {} ). Why this? I just want the JSonObject tree that I had on the other side, not an object serialization. Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
JsonObject jsobj = new Gson().fromJson(cmdstr, JsonObject.class)
```

will try and build a type of JsonObject from the string - which your string clearly isn't.

I think what you want to do is get the raw parse tree - which you can do like this:

```
JsonObject jsobj = new JsonParser().parseString(cmdstr);
```

See [this](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) for more details.